# React-Native Build failed with EAS - Build failed - Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, ../node_modules/semver/bin/semver.js’

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, command-line-interface

I'm working on **Mac M1**
**Expo sdk:** "^41.0.0"
**React-Native :** "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-41.0.0.tar.gz"
**eas-cli/0.21.0 darwin-x64 node-v15.14.0**
**expo-cli:** "4.8.1"

My project is a monorepo and we work with yarn workspace.
When I run this command : **eas build --profile preview --platform all**  all credentials are ok, but the build filed with this error :

[image]

I have tried to remove and re-install node_modules but not working ...
I don't understand this error, why and how I can fix it ...
Any Idea?

Comment: This happened with me once, What i did was I deleted the Project from expo Dashboard and also the git repo which gets initialized while building EAS build and it got fixed. In short, what I did was created a new build with a new repo from scratch.

Comment: thx @Kartikey but I'm not the only one on the repo and I can't recreate a new repo ...